# Is there a way to immediatey hide a currently displayed tooltip?

Tags: java, events, tooltip, awt

Typically my tooltips display for about 5 seconds and that is ok in most situations, but if the user presses 'Enter' I need it to go away immediately because it still sticks out from behind a new dialog that I show due to their keyboard action.  Everything I've found so far just suggests setting it to null but that has no effect until the next time it would be shown, whereas I need the currently showing one to go away immediately.  Is there a way to do this with java awt/swing?

Comment: Can you provide your already produced code? This way we can help you better.

Comment: "Enter" is pressed to close the tooltip or as action to trigger a process, that usually display this tooltip ?

Comment: The component with the tool tip is a JTextField where the tooltip is set when instantiated and a KeyListener on it for the Enter key will pop up a JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog, that covers most of the tooltip but not all of it.  Noted that if a mouse double-click is used instead of Enter, the tooltip goes away immediately.  But to 'fix' this problem for the Enter key, I have decided to make the confirm dialog larger and my tooltip shorter, thereby sweeping this problem 'under the rug'.  By the time a user might move the confirm dialog the obscured tooltip will have evaporated anyway.